# How can be nxserver reinstalled from command line (UBUNTU)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How can be [nxserver](http://www.nomachine.com/download-package.php?Prod_Id=2069) reinstalled from command line (UBUNTU)?

Edit:
I download the files like suggested and run:

```
# sudo apt-get remove nxserver
# sudo dpkg -i nxserver_3.4.0-14_i386.deb
```

But I get this errors:

```
Setting up nxserver (3.4.0-14) ...
NX> 704 ERROR: Cannot add user: nx.
NX> 704 ERROR: User: nx already exists.
NX> 704 To fix the problem, you may try to completely uninstall NX
NX> 704 Server and install it from scratch. If this is not enough,
NX> 704 please delete the nx user by using the system commands and
NX> 704 proceed with a new installation of NX Server.
dpkg: error processing nxserver (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nxserver
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run these commands:

- `sudo apt-get remove nxserver`
  Remove the server.
- `wget http://64.34.161.181/download/3.4.0/Linux/FE/nxserver_3.4.0-14_i386.deb`
  To download the installation .deb.
- `sudo gdebi nxserver_3.4.0-14_i386.deb`
  (Assuming you don't have anything else in that dir you're running it from) Uses gdebi to install the downloaded deb.

Here's a code block so you can copy the whole thing into your terminal and let it run:

```
sudo apt-get remove nxserver && wget http://64.34.161.181/download/3.4.0/Linux/FE/nxserver_3.4.0-14_i386.deb && sudo gdebi nxserver_3.4.0-14_i386.deb
```

Comment: please see the error that i get in my edit

Comment: @meyosef: Did you try the remove?

Comment: Instead of `sudo apt-get remove nxserver` you may want to try `sudo apt-get purge nxserver`. Keep in mind that it'll delete your settings though.

Comment: Thank you, I make your advise(purge) but still its gives me same error.
I purge first client then node then server (Its gives me warnings that its cant remove some directories).

dpkg: warning: while removing nxnode, directory '/usr/NX/etc' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing nxnode, directory '/usr/NX/var' not empty so not removed.
Removing nxclient ...
Purging configuration files for nxclient ...
dpkg: warning: while removing nxclient, directory '/usr/NX' not empty so not removed.

Comment: Perhaps you should just remove the directory yourself: `sudo rm -rf /usr/NX`

Comment: I also remove the directory but nothing change

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [instructions here](http://www.nomachine.com/documents/server/install.php) for a DEB package.

Download the package using `wget`:

```
wget http://64.34.161.181/download/3.4.0/Linux/FE/nxserver_3.4.0-14_i386.deb
```

Issue this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i nxserver_3.4.0-14_i386.deb
```

Comment: I already try it before and get:

NX> 704 ERROR: Cannot add user: nx.
NX> 704 ERROR: User: nx already exists.
NX> 704 To fix the problem, you may try to completely uninstall NX
NX> 704 Server and install it from scratch. If this is not enough,
NX> 704 please delete the nx user by using the system commands and
NX> 704 proceed with a new installation of NX Server.
dpkg: error processing nxserver (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nxserver

Answer (score 0):

This may help on Unbuntu as well.

On Linux Mint 15,

I found the nxserver folder to be at /usr/NX/scripts/setup and cd to the setup folder.
Then I ran the command - $sudo ./nxserver --uninstall
and the same for nxnode - $sudo ./nxnode --uninstall

Then cd to /usr and remove /NX folder

After that I was able to install the latest nxserver 4